# How would I uninstall and reinstall SQL Server 2019 with the problems listed below?

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to uninstall and reinstall sql server but I ran into a number of problems.
[image]
The first of which is after I deleted the files and components for sql server 2019 I ran into this several times during reinstallation. Of course I did try rebooting but this results in the error prompting up again. I believe the main problem is the left over services/files no matter what I try I can't delete.
[image]
When I try to get the remove prompt from sql server 2019 it instead shows me this which I believe is a result of the failed installation since it couldn't correctly download so I don't have that as an option.

[image]
As you can see I can't remove setup either because of the files that are dependent on it. Unfortunately to delete the existing databases and probably the other files I need the remove prompt that you would normally get from choosing remove in the sql server 2019 uninstall but since as I listed previously I don't have access to that so I have no way to delete these services or files.

I'm honestly at a loss for what to do because I can neither uninstall the previous files or reinstall them because of the errors so I am stuck. I have tried alot of solutions by googling but to no avail, if anyone has any idea what to do help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to check the [log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15) and if you not find any useful info try to remove (move to tmp) the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`.

Comment: Ok ill try that but what should moving it to tmp do?

Comment: If you don't want to permanently delete the folder and would try other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the generic steps to repair, reinstall, or uninstall the SQL Server 2019/2022 and remove the residual files:**

First, try downloading SQL Server 2019 (Dev Edition) from the Microsoft website and attempt to repair it using this link: https://download.microsoft.com/download/d/a/2/da259851-b941-459d-989c-54a18a5d44dd/SQL2019-SSEI-Dev.exe

**If the repair/reinstall doesn't work, you can uninstall SQL Server from the setup itself and get ready for a fresh installation.**

**Note:** When you uninstall, not everything will be removed from your system `(this happens a lot on my system ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ )`

- A couple of **entries in the Registry** (I don't delete them, but it's up to you what you want to do with them).
- Two apps in the "**Installed Apps**" section in Windows:
- `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit)`
- `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup`

There isn't a direct way to uninstall these apps, but there is a workaround.

**"Settings" --> "Apps" -- > "Installed Apps"** (filter the apps by searching "SQL Server")

Remove all the Apps which has SQL Server in their name (you will be able to remove all but two apps 1. Microsoft SQL Server 2. Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup)

In the "Installed Apps" section, select **"**Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup**."
Click on (---) and choose "Uninstall."**

You'll see a User Account Control dialogue box asking "**Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?**".

**`Don't click on "Yes" or "No"`**

Instead, click on "**Show More Details**"

Note down the installer location, which will look something like "C:\Windows\Installer\SomeWeirdName.msi"

Open the Installer folder and run **SomeWeirdName.msi** file. This will remove the remaining SQL Server components.

Now, restart your computer and proceed with a fresh installation of SQL Server.
Hope I was able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of our user.
I had to repair the SQL server instance from the Setup file and after a reboot it worked like a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).